# Angular 2 Routing - ModuleWithProviders v NgModule

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm working on a MEAN project via Angular 2, and am setting up the routing for my various pages. I've seen a lot of examples that use ModuleWithProviders to do routing, rather than the angular.io example with NgModule (https://angular.io/guide/router)

Which is the standard way of doing things? If either is acceptable, is there a performance difference between the two?

ModuleWithProviders example:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { ServicesComponent } from './services/services.component';

export const router: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'about', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
    { path: 'services', component: ServicesComponent }
];

export const routes: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(router);
```

NgModule Example:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { ServicesComponent } from './services/services.component';

export const router: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'about', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
    { path: 'services', component: ServicesComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot( router )
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

NgModule and ModuleWithProviders are different things.

`NgModule` is a decorator for module classes.

[`ModuleWithProviders` is the interface](https://angular.io/api/core/ModuleWithProviders) that is supposed to be returned by `forRoot` method. `ModuleWithProviders` object is plain object that has `ngModule` property that contains actual module class augmented with additional providers in `providers` property.

Since `ModuleWithProviders` is an interface, its usage is optional.

Comment: Thanks for the information but I think the question is not fully answered. Is one of the two ways superior?

Comment: I believe it was answered. They are apples and oranges. Their comparison is incorrect. NgModule is a real thing. ModuleWithProviders is a type, its use is optional and affects only TS type checking.

Comment: Ok, but both ways work when declaring routes. Which one is to prefer?

Comment: To be precise, 'ModuleWithProviders vs NgModule' comparison is incorrect. As for the examples, one of them wraps routings with another module. Another one doesn't. It makes sense to create AppRoutingModule module if contains `providers` and `declarations` that are used in routes. This isn't shown in the example, so AppRoutingModule is pretty much useless there.

Comment: Sure, no problems.

Answer (score 12):

[estus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3731501/estus) is absolutely right about the difference between the two (`@NgModule` is a decorator while `ModuleWithProvider` is an interface) but practically speaking, the answer to your question that which approach is better would be:

The second approach is more clear, more common and the best practice because it defines the routes in a **separate module** which it will be later imported to `AppModule`:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'about', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
    { path: 'services', component: ServicesComponent }
];

const config: ExtraOptions = {
  useHash: true
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, config)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})    
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Importing to `AppModule`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [AppRoutingModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Although, what mentioned above hopefully answered your question, I like to also point out the difference between importing `RouterModule` in `AppModule` and sub-modules:

For the `AppModule`:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
```

For sub-modules:

```
RouterModule.forChild(routes)
```

Why? `RouterModule` gives you

- a **component** (router-outlet)
- a **directive** (routerLink)
- also **services** (ActivatedRoute to get URL params, Router to
  navigate ...)

The first time in app module, `forRoot` will give the router components and provide the router services. But the next times in sub-modules, `forChild` will only give the router components (and not providing again the services, which are already available via the app module import).

Want to read more? I found [this article](https://medium.com/@cyrilletuzi/understanding-angular-modules-ngmodule-and-their-scopes-81e4ed6f7407) amazing.